# necesito ayuda con consulta en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos que se llama tiempos, esta tabla tiene en total 18 campos, dentro de la tabla se registran camiones repetidos.

Lo que se registra del camión es: id, fecha, turno, camión, posición de la llanta y tiempo de atención.

estoy intentando calcular el tiempo de atención por cada llanta pero la única manera de hacerlo es que la consulta me tome por decir la fecha de hoy, luego me cuente si el camión se le atendieron más de una llanta y si es así que me divida el tiempo de atención del primer registro de camión entre la cantidad de llantas, osea entre el numero de veces que se registro ese camión en esa misma fecha.

Entonces como podría hacer una consulta en mysql y php que sea capaz de contar cuantas veces se registro el camión en x fecha y dependiendo del nro de veces que se registro el camión que tome la variable de tiempo de atención y la divida entre la cantidad total de llantas.

Les dejo lo que tengo:

Consulta actual:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>FECHA</td>
    <td>TURNO</td>
    <td>FLOTA</td>
    <td>EQUIPO</td>
    <td>POSICIÓN</td>
    <td>TIEMPO DE ATENCIÓN</td>
  </tr>

<?PHP

$sql=mysql_query("select tiempos.* from tiempos order by fecha ASC");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){        

    $id=$res["id"];
    $fecha=$res["fecha"];
    $turno=$res["turno"];
    $flota=$res["flota"];
    $equipo=$res["equipo"];
    $pos=$res["pos"];
    $ti_attenequi=$res["ti_attenequi"];

?>  
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fecha; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $turno; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $flota; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $equipo; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pos; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ti_attenequi; ?></td>
 </tr> 
  <?php
}
  ?>
</table>
```

Actualmente toda esa información viene de la tabla que se llama -tiempos- ya con otro formulario guardo esa info. sin problemas.

Entonces por un lado estaba pensando en usar algun condicional con php, y crear una columna nueva que se llame -tiempo por llanta- y allí que se guarde el tiempo que necesito calcular.

Comment: La funcion mysql_query fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi

Comment: Si lo se, solo estoy usando eso de manero local, a modo de prueba, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, lo que necesitas es una clausula group by

```
select id, fecha, turno, flota, equipo, posicion, SUM(ti_attenequi) as ti_attenequi FROM tiempos group by flota, fecha
```

Comment: Acabo de probar esa consulta pero me suma todo el tiempo de atención por camión, la consulta tendría que tomar la fecha primero y contar la cantidad de veces que este un camión luego dividir el tiempo de atención por cada registro que se encuentre por camión y por fecha.

Comment: Podrías darme datos de ejemplo para entender mejor tu pregunta?

Comment: ok, datos de ejemplo, otra cosa el tiempo de atención esta en horas: camión: 220250  posición: 1 tiempo de atención: 1 fecha: 2019-11-28. entonces un camión puede tener x cantidad de registros por día, cambia es la posición, entonces la idea es que si el equipo tiene 2 registros el día 2019-11-28 que divida el tiempo down del primer registro entre la cantidad total entonces seria con este ejemplo asi: 1 hora entre / dos registro = 0.5 horas

Comment: Segun entiendo, la columna ti_attenequi representa el tiempo de atencion de un camion, no de una llanta. Entonces la consulta debería ser así: select id, fecha, turno, flota, ti_attenequi/COUNT(flota) as tiempo_por_llanta FROM tiempos group by flota, fecha

Comment: adelante de la variable ti_attenequi/ ese caracter esta demas? el /

Comment: Es el caracter de division, tiempo de atencion dividido entre el numero de registros (attenequi/COUNT(flota))

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma pero no funciono, de todas formas muchas gracias.